# Comparing two dates by week in a .NET entity framework LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there an easy way of comparing weeks in two dates like this...

```
var times = (from d in db.TimeSet
             where d.EventDate.Week) == DateTime.ThisWeek &&                         
             d.Employee.Username == username
             select d).ToList();
```

Comment: 6 questions, 0 accepted answer. I'm sure that you *WON'T* get an answer.

Comment: does that mean you don't know or just bored?

Comment: that means you have no respect for the time & knowledge that other people care to share with you.

Comment: Actually, if you check the profile now at least, that's 4 accepted answers. Not so bad.

Comment: so ticking a green icon gives respect? hmm, never realised that. Thanks to people like you scouring this site for non respectful users, I have now realised my terrible ways and endeavour to correct them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime date)
{
        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        int weekNum = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        return weekNum;
}
```

and

```
var times = (from d in db.TimeSet
             where GetWeekNumber(d.EventDate) == GetWeekNumber(DateTime.Now) &&                         
             d.Employee.Username == username
             select d).ToList();
```

You might want to look into [CalendarWeekRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx) to pick the one that fits your needs.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetWeekNumber(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: The only thing I had to edit was DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.ThisWeek. Otherwise, it seems to compile for me.